# Printing to terminal while using output buffering in CLI PHP scripts

Tags: php, command-line

I'm using command line PHP to build some files offline. To capture the script output I use the standard ob_start stuff:

```
ob_start();
// Echo lots of stuff
$content = ob_get_contents();
// Now the $content can be written to a file
```

However, I also want to print some messages to the terminal (for instance, warnings) *while* collecting the "main output" into the buffer. Is there a way to do this? It doesn't seem to be possible to pause the buffering for a while to print the terminal messages, and then continue the buffering from where it was left. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just write to STDOUT or STDERR (both constants containing file pointer resources) using fputs():

```
ob_start();
echo 'Output buffer';
fputs(STDOUT, "Log message");
$x = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();;

echo "X = $x";
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `php://stderr` stream:

```
$f = fopen('php://stderr', 'w');
fputs($f, 'Output');
```

**EDIT:** Also, in CLI, there is a [predefined STDERR constant](http://php.net/CLI):

```
fputs(STDERR, 'Output');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to 'pause' an output buffer. Write the contents of the buffer to a variable, and end the buffer without flushing. Write some non-buffered output, and call ob_start() again. This method uses string concatenation, and it's a relatively dirty method. I prefer the other methods above my own for this reason.

But in either case, here's a small, working example:

```
<?php
ob_start();
    echo 'Buffered line 1.<br>';
$ob = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo 'Non-buffered line.<br>';

ob_start();
    echo 'Buffered line 2.<br>';
$ob .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo 'Non-buffered line.<br>';

ob_start();
    echo 'Buffered line 3.<br>';
$ob .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo 'Non-buffered line.<br>';

echo $ob;
?>
```